# mysql query to select students with preference

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables called: majorsubjets, students and entries.

The subjects table has the fields: subject_id, subject_name .

The students table has the fields: student_id, name etc.

The entries table has 2 foreign keys linked to subject_id and student_id which are both primary keys of the above tables and choice column having values 1, 2,3,4 for recording (Choice 1, choice 2, choice 3, choice 4).

the entries table has four entries per student having 4 dirrefent subject_id

. How do I display the names of students with a all subject choice he opted?

student_tbl

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |

majorsubjects

| id | subName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sub1 |
| 2 | sub2 |
| 3 | sub3 |
| 4 | sub4 |
| 5 | sub5 |

entries_tbl

| id | student_ID | subject_id | preference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 4 |

Result should be like: (prefrence->pref)

| id | name | pref1 | pref2 | pref3 | pref4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | sub4 | sub3 | sub1 | sub5 |
| 2 | BBB | sub3 | sub5 | sub13 | sub2 |

Comment: You already asked the same question. You didn't even fix `choice` to be `preference` when you reposted, even though I pointed out that error and you agreed that it was a mistake.

Comment: Can you please make a mysql query for it

Comment: I gave you a link to another question that shows how to do the pivot part. The rest is a simple `JOIN`.